# render with locals inside js.erb doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial-views, erb

Why render why `:locals` doesn't work when it called from `js.erb` file?

this my `create.js.erb`:

```
$("#div").before("<%= escape_javascript(render("/admin/products/variant_image_preview", :locals => {:image => @variant_image})) %>");
```

`variant_image_preview.html.erb`:

```
<div id="variant_image_<%= image.id %>">

  <%= image_tag image.image_url(:thumb), width: 114, height: 88 %>
  <% form_name = "product[variants_attributes][1][images_attributes][#{Time.now.to_f}]" %>

  <input type="hidden" value="<%= image.id %>" name="<%= form_name %>[id]">

  <a id="<%= image.id %>" class="remove_image" title="Remover imagem">
    <img src="/assets/bg_close.png" alt="Remover imagem">
  </a>
</div>
```

At first line of variant_image_preview.html.erb I get this error:

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `image' for #<#<Class:0x0000000f4f6e88>:0x000000101332c8>:
```

Some posts on StackOverflow say that this code should work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the syntax that you use the locals should be passed as the second argument, like this:

```
render("/admin/products/variant_image_preview", :image => @variant_image)
```

You can replace this syntax with more declarative call:

```
render(partial: "/admin/products/variant_image_preview", :locals => {:image => @variant_image})
```